# VBA Provider Microsoft.ACE.OLDEDB.12.0 for CSV file and sum of values in column doesn't work

Tags: vba, csv, oledb

I have problem with sql query for some columns. 
In VBA I use this code for opening database:

```
 db.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & Dirname(Name) & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=CSVDelimited;MaxScanRows=0"""
```

And in sql query I want to sum column *mv* according to *group* (AFS or HTM) with corresponding *time* - and it works.

But for column *sold* it doesn't work - probably this column looks like string column instead of value/double because in first aproximately 1000 rows nothing or zero is. I tried to solve it with different ways, e.g. MaxScanRows=0 or IMEX=1, or schema.ini but it doesn't work...

Example of csv file:

Thanks in advance for any advice